# Regex: Matching comma not followed by a number

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to extract some groups from command-like strings with the form:

1. foo(bar,1). > need 'foo', 'bar' and '1'
2. foo(bar,1.1). > need 'foo', 'bar' and '1.1'
3. foo(bar-{foo,bar},1.1). > need 'foo', 'bar-{foo,bar}' and '1.1'

So a comma can be present in the first argument!

Since the second argument is always beginning with a digit, I could match for the first argument commas which are not followed by a number, but I just can't do it with lookahead :(

Here is my tries so far:

```
(\w+)\(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\{\}~]+)(,(\d+(\.\d+)?))?\)\.
```

... but example 3 won't match this one.

```
(\w+)\(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\{\}~\,(?!\d)]+)(,(\d+(\.\d+)?))?\)\.
```

... this one won't let me catch the groups > 2 (negative lookahead doesn't affect the first comma)

Here's the [Debuggex example](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dlMLAdKjcrYvKxv0)

Any help will be appreciated! Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: What kind of symbols negate the comma?  Only a `{``}`?  What do you want to happen with `foo(bar[1,2],3)`?

Comment: Whet language are you using?

Comment: @SamSullivan: Only {} negate the comma. Other cases can't happen.

Comment: @Bohemian: I'm using java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If {} are supposed to contain anyting then maybe this will work?

```
(\w+)\(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-~]+(\{.*\})?),(.+)\)\.
```

Comment: Supposing {} can contain anything, which I'd say is the case, this works like a charm so I accept this answer :) Thanks Maciek

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
(.*?)(?:\(|\)|,(?=\d))
```

Expl.: Match anything up to either a '(', ')' or a ',' followed by a digit.

If you want arbitrary spaces to be allowed:

```
\s*(.*?)\s*(?:\(|\)|,(?=\d))\s*
```

Use global flag to get all instances.

Regards

Comment: This does work indeed, but I'm not sure I'll be able to catch the different groups (using Java)! Thank you for your answer ClasG :)